# What does "400 Bad request" mean in HTTP2 APNs response?

Tags: apple-push-notifications, http2

By using the new HTTP2 APNs [Notification API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/APNsProviderAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW18), there is a response code `400 Bad request` returns. What does this mean? Invalid token? Invalid payload? Or anything else?

Thanks.

Comment: I guess it means the same as in in HTTP 1, malformed request. Error codes aren't that specific, you should seek about more details in the response message.

Comment: You should probably ask Apple that...

Comment: It's late now, there's a "reason" data that describes the nature of the error, you can reference Table 6-6 from [Notification API documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/APNsProviderAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW18)

Answer (score 2):

You can check the payload, it will have reason along with 400 error code.

> PayLoad = {"reason":"BadDeviceToken"}

In my case we used debug build to point to production APNS and APNS rejected with 400